# Have 10 starbursts and 6 milky ways. I have 3 sisters. How many ways can I share with my 3 sisters?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I thought this was a combination with repetition problem but am stuck. I thought it would be (16 + (4-1)) choose (4-1) but this isn't the answer.

How does this change if each of my sisters get at least one of each type of candies (a starburt and a milkyway?)

Comment: Define "share". Does everyone have to receive the same number of sweets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stars and bars.  You can distribute $10$ starburts among $4$ people in $\binom{13}{3}$ ways, and $6$ milky ways in $\binom{9}{3}$ ways.  The number of ways to do both is the product  $$\binom{13}{3}\binom{9}{3}$$

**EDIT**

If each of the $3$ sisters must get at least one of each type of candy, just give them each one to begin with, and then distribute the rest among all four.  For example, for the starbursts, we'd have $7$ candies left to distribute among $4$ people, so there would be $\binom{10}{3}$ ways to do it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. How does this change if the question changes to how many different ways can the candies be distributed if my sisters get at least one of each type of candies?

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you. I'm learning combinatorics now and was confused before your answer helped clarify. I appreciate it.

Comment: It was my pleasure.